# Audio.play() causes tiny lag

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, three.js

**Problem:**
I have made a flappy-bird like game using Three.js. Everytime I tap the screen, a "flap"-sound is played. However playing this audio causes a tiny lagg, which makes the game less smooth. If I remove the sound, all lagg disappears. The lagg only appears as the audio is played, not while the audio is playing.

**Audio set-up:** 
First I set up the audio like this:

```
var soundFly = new Audio();
soundFly.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/tj7mxg26egzo4zx/flap.wav?dl=0";
soundFly.preload = "auto";
```

Next I load all audio upon starting the game (on button click):

```
function loadAudio()
{
soundFly.play().then(function () {
   soundFly.pause()
   }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log("soundFly - " + e)
            });           
};
```

Then, everytime I touch the screen, I play the sound:

```
this.soundFly.play().catch(function (e)     {
    console.log("soundFly - " + e)
})
```

This works great, but the tiny lagg appears.

**Rendering:**
This is how I set up the rendering of the scene:

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var delta=0;
clock.start(); //makes rendering timedependent

var render = function ()
{

delta = clock.getDelta();

//All movement is set using speed*delta

requestAnimationFrame(render);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

**FPS:**
I have also checked how the audio.play() affects the FPS. My FPS is steady at about 59. But when I play the audio, the FPS drops to between 20-30, which probably is what causes the tiny lagg (see picture):

[Audio.play() affecting FPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTsaG.jpg)

I checked FPS using this:

```
console.log(1/delta);
```

And also outputting "flapp" to the console when touching screen.

I hope someone has an explanation to this!

Best regards,
Joakim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you use HTML5 audio for interactive sound effects. The API is not intended for this purpose. Instead, use the Web Audio based classes like `THREE.Audio` or `THREE.PositionalAudio` which allow sound effects without delay and appropriate timing.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webaudio_timing

Also read the following [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) for more information. It says:

*Timing is controlled with high precision and low latency, allowing developers to write code that responds accurately to events...*

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna try this!

Comment: Update: I now implemented Three.Audio, and ALL lagg is removed! Awesome! Thanks a lot @Mugen87!